# SSRS 2008r2 Using Aggregate on field with an Expression

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

SSRS 2008r2

I'm trying to perform an aggregate (Sum) on a field within a GROUPing that contains an expression.

The field where I want to SUM to appear is within a different GROUPing.

I've created the following Function within Report Properties

```
Dim public tot_OT_Hrs As Decimal 

Public Function Add_OT_Hrs(ByVal OT_Hrs As Decimal) AS Decimal 

    tot_OT_Hrs = tot_OT_Hrs + OT_Hrs 

    return OT_Hrs 

End Function 

Public Function GetTotal() 
    return tot_OT_Hrs 
End Function
```

I've added a call to the "Add_OT_Hrs" function in the field where the expression is and this works fine.

```
=Code.Add_OT_Hrs(
    IIF(Sum(Fields!HrsWorked.Value) > Parameters!StdWorkingHrs.Value, 
        Sum(Fields!HrsWorked.Value) - Parameters!StdWorkingHrs.Value + Sum(Fields!Rate1Hrs.Value)
            , Sum(Fields!Rate1Hrs.Value ) 
        )
    )
```

Fields!Rate1Hrs.Value is the field in which the expression resides in and Fields!HrsWorked.Value is an adjacent field

However, the field where I want to total to appear I've added the following

```
=Code.GetTotal()
```

All that is returned here is 0 (zero) on every row in the GROUPing.  If I initialise the Dim public tot_OT_Hrs As Decimal variable to say 1.2 then 1.2 is returned on every row in the GROUPing.  The Add_OT_Hrs function isn't working as expected.

[image: screenshot]

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the expression that you are using for the Add_OT_Hrs field

Comment: I've updated the question with the expression  @SFrejofsky.  Fields!Rate1Hrs.Value is the field in which the expression resides in and Fields!HrsWorked.Value is an adjacent field

Comment: Try implicitly converting you sum and values to decimal. There may be an error there as SSRS does not alway handle conversions correctly especially if your textbox is set to general and not a specific datatype. you could also remove the iif statement and work solely with a sum and see what your returned values are.

Comment: I have changed the textbox properties to Number,  It was set to General.  I have removed the IIF statement and left the sum in place `=Code.Add_OT_Hrs(Format(CDbl(Sum(Fields!Rate1Hrs.Value)),"00.00"))` and I'm still getting zero.

Comment: If I initialise the tot_OT_Hrs variable like so `public tot_OT_Hrs As Decimal = 1.2` then the return from the `GetTotal()` function is 1.2.  it seems the `Add_OT_Hrs` function is working correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are converting in the wrong order and also to the wrong data type. In the code example that you used you were converting the sum to a double which is not the correct data type. There is a notable difference between a double and decimal when using custom functions.

I tested this with a very small dataset as follows

```
select '1.2'
union all 
select '1.8'
```

Then applied the following custom code

```
Dim public total as decimal
Public Function AddTotalr(ByVal r AS decimal) AS decimal
            total = total + r
            return r

End Function

Public Function GetTotalr()
            return total
End Function
```

The order of your explicit conversion is vital. You have to convert the value before you sum the total so that you are working with consistent data types.

```
=code.addtotalr(sum(cdec(Fields!ID.Value)))
```

[image]

Even with the correct data type the this will produce an error because you are attempting to sum what is, most likely, being interpreted as a character string.

```
=code.addtotalr(cdec(sum(Fields!ID.Value)))
```

[image]

-----------edit ------------------------

As a test to see what the return on the function is change your function to

```
Dim public total as decimal
Public Function AddTotalr(ByVal r AS decimal) AS decimal
        total = total + r
        return total
```

This should give you a running total of the items processed and the last value in the list should match what your total should be.

[image]

Comment: I've made the following change to the expression    

`=Code.Add_OT_Hrs(
 IIF(Sum(cdec(Fields!HrsWorked.Value)) > cdec(Parameters!StdWorkingHrs.Value), 
  Sum(cdec(Fields!HrsWorked.Value)) - cdec(Parameters!StdWorkingHrs.Value) + Sum(cdec(Fields!Rate1Hrs.Value))
   , Sum(cdec(Fields!Rate1Hrs.Value ) )
  )
 )`  
 
and the value being returned is still 0.00..

Comment: have you confirmed that this IIF statement will return the correct value per field if you remove the code.add_ot_hrs()

Comment: Yes.  With or without the code.add_ot_hrs()  the IIF statement returns the correct value.  Is it because the fields reside in different GROUPS that may be causing the problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be as you are circumventing the grouping by using the custom function. Are you by chance using multiple custom functions?

Comment: Nope, these are the only custom functions in the report.

Comment: This is a long shot but have you attempted deleting the local report cache.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the original question above to show where the expressions reside.

Comment: Create a textbox that is completely disconnected from the rest of the tablix and add the Total to the textbox expression and this will tell us if it something to do with the grouping or the function

Comment: Did that, added this to the expression of the textbox `=Code.GetTotal()` and I get 0.00.

Comment: I decided to do this in the proc.
It works out quite well now.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do this in the proc.
It works out quite well now.