# SSRS 2008R2 - Calculation in row group expression not working due to aggregation of varying data types - is this due to negative values?

Tags: t-sql, expression, ssrs-2008-r2, negative-number

The expression in the 'Net Effect' row in the second table is giving #Error as the result(the expression is using aggregate function on data of varying data types). The same expression works in the other tables but this table does have negative values where the count type = "Renewed Member" in the matrix.  Is that what is causing the issue?  Would negative values be classed as a different data type?

[image: Report Layout]

In my sql query I have converted the NULL values to 0.00 using this:

```
SELECT COUNT(x.ccx_membershipid) as CountAll
                , x.FinancialYear
                , x.Month3Char
                , x.MonthSort
                , SUM(ISNULL(x.ccx_membershipfee,0.00)) AS FeeTotal
                , x.CountType

FROM #Merged X
```

My Expression is:

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!CountType.Value="New Member",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00))
+
Sum(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Win-back",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00))
+
Sum(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Renewed Member",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00))
-
Sum(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Inactive Companies",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00))
-
Sum(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Lapsed Member",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00))
-
Sum(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Resigned/Cancelled Member",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00))
```

There are no text values that I can see.  If it is indeed the negative values that are causing the issue how do I get around that?
Thank you in advance for any advice that you can give.

Comment: What is the datatype of `ccx_membershipfee`?

Comment: Negative numbers will not give you this error. However any type misalignments: { strings, ints, reals, money, float, bool } will give you frustrating errors like this. Even though the math should be fine, you still need to cast to similar types for some reason.

Comment: @Thom_A - datatype of ccx_membershipfee is 'money'.

Comment: @tgolisch - each of the individual parts of the expression are summing a money datatype would I still need to cast to a similar type if they are all the same?

Comment: @tgolisch - I started researching previous posts after reading your comment and found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126101/ssrs-2008r2-using-aggregate-on-field-with-an-expression - so I added Cdec around my expression AFTER the SUM and it is now working so thank you for the point in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post: [SSRS 2008r2 Using Aggregate on field with an Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126101/ssrs-2008r2-using-aggregate-on-field-with-an-expression)
Adding Cdec around my expression AFTER the SUM has made it work.

```
=SUM(Cdec(IIf(Fields!CountType.Value="New Member",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00)))
+
Sum(Cdec(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Win-back",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00)))
+
Sum(Cdec(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Renewed Member",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00)))
-
Sum(Cdec(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Inactive Companies",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00)))
-
Sum(Cdec(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Lapsed Member",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00)))
-
Sum(Cdec(IIF(Fields!CountType.Value="Resigned/Cancelled Member",Fields!FeeTotal.Value,0.00)
```